# Is there a way to easily manage Project options (custom-fields)

Tags: plugins, customization

Im currently rocking the Fluxus theme on a website for a client of mine. The theme offers project options (custom fields) where you could add in information about your artwork.

[image: See this picture]

As my client has over 100 artworks uploaded. Is there an easy way to manage these fields? He wants to add prices to all of them. But that would mean i have to edit them all piece by piece.

Im sure there is an easier way for this?

Kind Regards,

Gino Brugman

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Content Management. :)

In *general* post meta is easy to manipulate, it's just a key/value store for each post. From your screenshot, however, it seems to be a pretty custom implementation by theme that makes fields *individual* to it.

You will first have to take apart how exactly theme keeps track of its own fields and if it's friendly to modification. Another hunch this gives me is that it might not be friendly at all to *querying* by those values. And as soon as you have prices at some point client will likely want to sort/filter by them.

In a nutshell this is doable, but very specific to theme.

Hundred items isn't actually that many and editing that amount just might take less time in practice than working out and testing programmatic solution. Some of the more elaborate bulk import/edit problems I encountered in the past were very efficiently solved by "we had interns do it". :)

Comment: Alright thanks. Would i be able to do this with some sort of plugin? I have no interns :(

Comment: For a custom fields implementation unlikely. This isn't really a code problem, it's a business problem — what does make more sense between client managing their content themselves, paying you to manage it, or paying yout to develop code to import it.